# How to Retrieve Data from Out of Axios Function to Add to Array (NEWBIE QUESTION)

Tags: node.js, rest, axios

I am working on building a blog API for a practice project, but am using the data from an external API. (There is no authorization required, I am using the JSON data at permission of the developer)

The idea is that the user can enter multiple topic parameters into my API. Then, I make individual requests to the external API for the requested info.

For each topic query, I would like to:

1. Get the appropriate data from the external API based on the params entered (using a GET request to the URL)
2. Add the response data to my own array that will be displayed at the end.
3. Check if each object already exists in the array (to avoid duplicates).
4. res.send the array.

My main problem I think has to do with understanding the scope and also promises in Axios. I have tried to read up on the concept of promise based requests but I can't seem to understand how to apply this to my code.

I know my code is an overall mess, but if anybody could explain how I can extract the data from the Axios function, I think it could help me get the ball rolling again.

Sorry if this is a super low-level or obvious question - I am self-taught and am still very much a newbie!~ (my code is a pretty big mess right now haha)

Here is a screenshot of the bit of code I need to fix:

```
   router.get('/:tagQuery', function(req, res){
  const tagString = req.params.tagQuery;
  const tagArray = tagString.split(',');


  router.get('/:tag', function(req, res){
    const tagString = req.params.tag;
    const tagArray = queryString.split(',');

  const displayPosts = tagArray.map(function(topic){

      const baseUrl = "https://info.io/api/blog/posts";
          return axios
            .get(baseUrl, {
              params: {
                tag: tag
              }
            })
            .then(function(response) {
              const responseData = response.data.posts;

              if (tag === (tagArray[0])){
                 const responseData = response.data.posts;
                 displayPosts.push(responseData);
               } else {
                 responseData.forEach(function(post){

                   // I will write function to check if post already exists in responseData array. Else, add to array

                 }); // End if/then
            })
            .catch(function(err) {
              console.log(err.message);
            }); // End Axios
        }); // End Map Function
        res.send(displayPosts);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Node.js is a single thread non-blocking, and according to your code you will respond with the result before you fetching the data.
you are using .map which will fetch n queries.

- use Promise.all to fetch all the requests || Promise.allsettled.
- after that inside the .then of Promise.all || promise.allsettled, map your result.
- after that respond with the mapped data to the user

```js
router.get('/:tag', function (req, res) {
    const tagString = req.params.tag;
    const tagArray = queryString.split(',');
    const baseUrl = "https://info.io/api/blog/posts";
    const topicsPromises=tagArray.map((tobic)=>{
        return axios
        .get(baseUrl, {
            params: {
                tag: tag
            }
        })
    });

    Promise.all(topicsPromises).then(topicsArr=>{
        //all the data have been fetched successfully
        // loop through the array and handle your business logic for each topic

        //send the required data to the user using res.send()
    }).catch(err=>{
        // error while fetching the data
    });
    
    
});
```

your code will be something like this.

note: read first in promise.all and how it is working.